# Getting a promise's value via yield & co

Tags: javascript, node.js, generator, ecmascript-harmony, co

I'm trying to figure out how to get the value of a promise via `yield`, possibly with "co":

```
function *(){
    var someVar = yield functionThatReturnsAPromise();
}
```

The called function is not a generator, just a normal function.  With the above, `someVar == Promise`, but I want the resolved value.  Does [co](https://github.com/visionmedia/co) or some other library have a way of doing this?

Comment: No, it is not true that `someVar == Promise`. `somevar` is equal to the value passed as a parameter to `next` by the function calling the iterator after it obtains the yielded value with the previous `next`.

Comment: @torazaburo -- You're right, but this is a nearly 2 year old answered question that you're just adding noise to...  Details that have _nothing_ to do with the actual question are irrelevant

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, **co** (https://github.com/tj/co) can do that. You'll have to wrap parent function inside `co` call:

```
co(function *(){
    var someVar = yield functionThatReturnsAPromise();
})()
```

`someVar` inside will become resolved value. If promise gets rejected, error can be cought with basic `try {} catch (e) {}` statements.

Comment: for me returns `Promise { <pending> }`

Comment: Why is this accepted answer and what exactly is "co", for me it say Uncaught ReferenceError: co is not defined"

Answer (score 8):

Typically a yield acts returns the same value to its own paused execution (left hand side of the yield function) as to the calling function of the generator. In this simple example counting from 1 to 5 example the input of the yield is the output of the yield to the generator function as well as to the generator's execution path:

```
function* inc() {
    var g = 0; 
    while (true) {
      g = yield g + 1;
    }
}

var incGen = inc();
for (i = incGen.next().value; i <= 5; i = incGen.next(i).value) {
  console.log(i);  //                                ^ input of generator is last output
}
```

However, the calling function may also call the generator, but replace the output the last yield with another value or even throw an exception to the generator's execution. In the case of promise a function that returns a promise, may yield the result of that promise instead of the promise itself. So in this case:

```
var someVar = yield functionThatReturnsAPromise();
     ^ output  !=   ^ input
```

you want the yield to act as a function that takes a promise as an input and returns a resolved promise as an output to the generator function.

It so happens `co` is able to do exactly this for you. All you need to do is feed your generator function to the `co` function:

```
co(function *(){
    var someVar = yield functionThatReturnsAPromise();
})
```

To better understand how this works, here is an example of a function, that does the same thing as co:

```
function async(makeGenerator){
  return function (){
    var generator = makeGenerator.apply(this, arguments)

    function handle(result){
      if (result.done) return result.value

      return result.value.then(function (res){
        return handle(generator.next(res))  // <- sets output of yield to the promise result
      }, function (err){                    //    and returns input promise 
        return handle(generator.throw(err)) // <- throw promise exception to generator function
      })
    }

    return handle(generator.next()) // <- first time call, input of yield is a promise
  }
}
```

[source is from Forbes Lindesay's now famous presentation about this concept](http://pag.forbeslindesay.co.uk/#/22)

Comment: *Typically a yield acts as a function that returns the same value to its own paused execution (left hand side of the yield function) as to the calling function of the generator. In this simple example the input of the yield is the output of the yield to the generator function as well as to the generator's execution path*. Actually I can't parse this sentence. However, I think it's wrong.

Comment: You can't use yield within your non-generator function `inc`.

Comment: @HåvardGeithus fixed